# Multiply all columns in an xts object by another single-column xts object

Tags: r, xts

```
library(xts)
set.seed(1)
x = xts( cbind(a=1:10,b=20:11) , Sys.Date()+1:10 )
y = xts( runif(10) , Sys.Date()+1:10 )
z = x*y
```

Gives me *Error in `*.default`(x, y) : non-conformable arrays*

What I want is to multiply each column in x by the value in y.

Expected result:

```
                   a         b
2012-08-04 0.2655087  5.310173
2012-08-05 0.7442478  7.070354
2012-08-06 1.7185601 10.311361
2012-08-07 3.6328312 15.439532
2012-08-08 1.0084097  3.226911
2012-08-09 5.3903381 13.475845
2012-08-10 6.6127269 13.225454
2012-08-11 5.2863823  8.590371
2012-08-12 5.6620264  7.549369
2012-08-13 0.6178627  0.679649
```

Ideally the solution should work when `index(x)!=index(y)`

ASIDE:
I came up with this hack:

```
 z = xts( apply(x,2,function(col) col*y ) , index(x) )
```

It works on the test data, but on my real data it complains with *Error in array(ans, c(len.a%/%d2, d.ans), if (!all(vapply(dn.ans, is.null,  :  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent*
(I've not managed to reproduce this in a small piece of test data yet.)

The answers by Joshua and DWin do not have this problem, so are superior not just in succinctness but also in quality of results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you just drop the dimensions of the single-column xts object.  Then R's recycling rules can take over.  This is slightly better than [DWin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789265/271616) because it will work correctly if `index(x) != index(y)`.

```
R> (z <- x*drop(y))
                   a         b
2012-08-03 0.2655087  5.310173
2012-08-04 0.7442478  7.070354
2012-08-05 1.7185601 10.311361
2012-08-06 3.6328312 15.439532
2012-08-07 1.0084097  3.226911
2012-08-08 5.3903381 13.475845
2012-08-09 6.6127269 13.225454
2012-08-10 5.2863823  8.590371
2012-08-11 5.6620264  7.549369
2012-08-12 0.6178627  0.679649
R> (z1 <- x*drop(y[1:5]))
                   a         b
2012-08-03 0.2655087  5.310173
2012-08-04 0.7442478  7.070354
2012-08-05 1.7185601 10.311361
2012-08-06 3.6328312 15.439532
2012-08-07 1.0084097  3.226911
```

Answer (score 3):

Not quite as slick as [JoshuaUlrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789393/967840), but for the sake of showing something different, you can use `sweep`

```
sweep(x, 1, y, "*")
#                   a         b
#2012-08-04 0.2655087  5.310173
#2012-08-05 0.7442478  7.070354
#2012-08-06 1.7185601 10.311361
#2012-08-07 3.6328312 15.439532
#2012-08-08 1.0084097  3.226911
#2012-08-09 5.3903381 13.475845
#2012-08-10 6.6127269 13.225454
#2012-08-11 5.2863823  8.590371
#2012-08-12 5.6620264  7.549369
#2012-08-13 0.6178627  0.679649
```

Comment: Thanks and confirmed this also works on the real data (i.e. even though apply doesn't, for a reason I don't understand yet). Joshua's answer does a logical AND when `index(y)` is a subset of `index(x)`, whereas this answer gives an error, and DWin's vector approach uses the recycling rule. (I.e. each might be the technique of choice for different applications.)

Answer (score 2):

Turn the y object into an ordinary vector:

```
> z <-  x * c(coredata(y))
> z
                      a             b
2012-08-03 0.2655086631  5.3101732628
2012-08-04 0.7442477993  7.0703540931
2012-08-05 1.7185600901 10.3113605403
2012-08-06 3.6328311600 15.4395324299
2012-08-07 1.0084096552  3.2269108966
2012-08-08 5.3903381098 13.4758452745
2012-08-09 6.6127268802 13.2254537605
2012-08-10 5.2863823399  8.5903713023
2012-08-11 5.6620263951  7.5493685268
2012-08-12 0.6178627047  0.6796489751
```